# Confirmation code not received while signUp with aws-amplify-react-native (Suddenly failed works still before)

Tags: react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Confirmation code not received while signUp with aws-amplify-react-native (Suddenly failed works still before)

Also, not received the code for confirmSignIn.